# twitter client help

Tags: android, twitter, oauth, twitter-oauth

I;m newbie to Android Development , i'm working in a small project that helps me to learn Android , it;s a Twitter Client , i'm using OAuth for authenticating the user to use Twitter's services and not using any callback urls, so i have to forward the user to a specific Twitter URL to get the PIN to continue the authenticating processes , after forwarding the user to the URL i wanna to force him to go back to my preferences activity write the PIN to continue the process , how this can be achieved ? any new ideas are welcomed..

Answer (score 0):

I have an example [here](http://schwiz.net/blog/2011/using-scribe-with-android/) using oauth to login to twitter on android without using the pins.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is the same but there is a tutorial on how to do the whole end-to-end [twitter OAuth integration here](http://automateddeveloper.blogspot.com/2011/06/android-twitter-oauth-authentication.html) with Twitter4J, and that returns Twitter to the activity to write the access details to the SharedPreferences by using a Callback url and handling the writing of the details in the original activity onResume() method.

It passes the Callback URL to the request to retrieve the tokens and then there is an Intent-Filter in the Manifest XML to return the request to the calling Activity.

Hope it helps.